# Creating Link to Main Domain User Profile In Buddypress

Tags: buddypress

I'm trying to write a new function so I can create a link that goes to the user's main domain members profile (I'm on a multisite.) The current `<a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>"><?php bp_loggedin_user_avatar( 'type=thumb&width=55&height=55' ) ?></a>` will take a user to the current domain member profile e.g. if I'm on site 2, it will return: http://site2.domain.com/members/username/
I need it to go to http://domain.com/members/username/

Right now, I've got:

`function bp_members_network_permalink() {
    echo bp_get_members_network_permalink();
}

```
function bp_get_members_network_permalink() {
    return apply_filters( 'bp_get_members_network_permalink', trailingslashit( network_home_url() . 'members/' . bp_member_user_id() ) );
}`
```

But on the front end, I only get: domain.com/members/

What am I missing? I've replaced "bp_member_user_id()" with "bp_loggedin_user_id()", "wp_get_current_user()", etc. but to no avail.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
<?php echo '/members/' . bp_core_get_username( bp_loggedin_user_id() ) . '/'; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've since abandoned trying to modify the the PHP directly in the files. I changed the wp-config.php file instead to use both: define('BP_ROOT_BLOG') and define('BP_MULTIBLOG') I had only defined multiblog before.